# pandas set one column equal to 1 but both df changes

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to get df `b` column `D` to be `1`, however, when I run this code, it also changes df `a` column `D` to `1` also... why is that, why are the variables linked? and how to I just change df `b` only?

```
import pandas as pd, os, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
a=df
b=df
b['D']=1
```

output:

```
>>> a
    A   B   C  D
0  98  84   3  1
1  13  35  76  1
2  17  84  28  1
3  22   9  41  1
4  54   3  20  1
>>> b
    A   B   C  D
0  98  84   3  1
1  13  35  76  1
2  17  84  28  1
3  22   9  41  1
4  54   3  20  1
>>>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`a`, `b` and `df` are references to the same object. When you change `b['D']`, you are actually changing that column of the actual object. Instead, it looks like you want to copy the DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd, os, numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
a=df.copy()
b=df.copy()
b['D']=1
```

which yields

```
b.head()
Out: 
    A   B   C  D
0  63  52  92  1
1  98  35  43  1
2  24  87  70  1
3  38   4   7  1
4  71  30  25  1

a.head()
Out: 
    A   B   C   D
0  63  52  92  80
1  98  35  43  78
2  24  87  70  26
3  38   4   7  48
4  71  30  25  61
```

There are also detailed responses [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-to-clone-or-copy-a-list).

Answer (score 2):

Don't use = when trying to copy a dataframe

use pd.DataFrame.copy(yourdataframe) instead

```
a = pd.DataFrame.copy(df)
b = pd.DataFrame.copy(df)
b['D'] = 1
```

This should solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You should use `copy`. Change

```
a=df
b=df
```

to

```
a=df.copy()
b=df.copy()
```

Check out [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy) reference where this issue is discussed a bit more in depth. I also had this confusion when I started using Pandas.